# Reducing code for random lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have created a program that will create 2 lists of random length filled with random numbers, and then tell me if there is a match between the 2 lists or not. I am quite new to this but just wanted to know if there is a way to maybe reduce all those random. functions when making these lists?

```
c = []
d = []

e = random.randrange(1,10)
f = random.randrange(e,100)
g = random.randrange(1,10)
h = random.randrange(1,10)

#print("This is g:", g)
#print("This is h:", h)

while g < 14:
    f = random.randrange(e, 124)
    c.append(f)
    g += 1

c.sort()
print(c)

while h < 14:
    f = random.randrange(e, 124)
    d.append(f)
    h += 1

d.sort()
print(d)

n = set(c) & set(d)

#print(bool(n))

if bool(n) == True:
    print("The following values are a match:", n)
elif bool(n) == False:
    print("No match")
```

Output

```
[14, 36, 80, 80, 120]
[14, 15, 28, 45, 52, 53, 63, 71, 83, 104, 110, 115]
The following values are a match: {14}
```

Comment: What does _random number of numbers_ mean ?

Comment: What's the purpose of your `while` loops?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but you can do `from random import randrange` and then use `randrange` directly

Comment: Well, for one thing, the first `f = ...` is unnecessary, as you reassign it again in the while loops before using it.

Comment: @Bck it means that I want to generate up to 13 random values between a range and put them in a list - I hope that explains it better

Comment: Side-note: `if bool(n) == True:` is an incredibly unPythonic (and slow) way to spell `if n:`. Similarly, `elif bool(n) == False:` is better as `elif not n:` (and in this case, you didn't need to test it at all the second time; since the only options are truthy or falsy, the even better spelling here would be `else:`). You should never compare anything to `True` or `False` (final recommendation [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)), and explicit conversion to `bool` is almost never necessary and slower than you might think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BcK's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4237254/bck) previous answer is fine, except it doesn't generate lists with random size (both have size = 30).
The code should be

```
a = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(random.randint(0, 30))]
b = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(random.randint(0, 30))]
common = set(a) & set(b)
if common:
    print(*common)
else:
    print("No match")
```

Comment: Not trying to be sulky but is it really decent to write the same answer with a tweak, instead of just commenting under my answer for correction or proposing an edit ? :)

Comment: @BcK sorry if it seems indecent, thanks for the advice. I will follow your advice from now :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the short version of your code I guess, still I am not sure what kind of *reduction* you want.

```
a = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(30)]
b = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(30)]

print(set(a) & set(b))
# {100, 91, 45, 78, 50, 51, 23, 59}
```

Comment: Thats something I was looking for.  I just wanted to see if there is any way to cut down on the lines so I dont have to write out almost the same thing over and over especially when I will need to make more lists.

Comment: Note: If you don't need the original `a` and `b` to be actual `list`s, you will save on peak memory use, and will almost certainly save time, by using `set` comprehensions in the first place, so you don't need to create two `list`s, and three `set`s. Just change to `a = {random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(30)}` (and similar for `b`), then change `the` print to the simpler `print(a & b)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree, just wrote those lists because OP wanted that way, in case he wants to do different things with the original ones.